# Serenity test issue No such file or directory

Tags: maven, jenkins, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to run tests using serenity and it works in local workstation(windows 10). But when I try executing via maven jenkins job (hosted on linux), I get no such file or directory issue

```
Oct 26, 2020 6:06:20 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request to {}->http://example.com:80: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/automation\src\main\resources\/test.gdb.zip (No such file or directory)
```

The file referred within /var/lib/jenkins/workspace does exist. Why is it unable to read the file?

Comment: Is your Jenkins linux hosted? Do you want to run on a Win node? Your path is a mix of ”/” and "\". Use ”/” and let jenkins translate.

Comment: @IanW, yes Jenkins is on Linux on which I get the error. On windows it works fine. Doesn't File.separator in Java automaticaly take forward or back slash depending on the OS it is run on?

Comment: "\" is a [unix escape character](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html), so it's rather one-way-ish. Also, depends on the code/circumstances/quoting, etc. I guess.